# How to use AutonumberAttribute.getNextNumber()?

Tags: c#, acumatica

When I use the AutonumberAttribute.getNextNumber(), it gives me the next number of the sequence but it also make the next number to change.

IE if I call 2 time in a row:

```
nextNumber = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(ARLetteringPiece.Cache, LetteringPiece, numbering, DateTime.Now);
```

first time i'll get "0000001"
second time i'll get "0000002"

I want to be able to know what the next number will be without modifying it's next value.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot

Edit to answer the comments :

I have a custom table, my UI key is generated with Autonumbering, and I need to put this key in the lines of my other tables to "bind" them to my custom table. So I need to know what will be the autogenerated number.

Comment: You'll have to give an idea of AutoNumberAttribute's implementation; it's not part of .Net.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. My question would by why would you need that? If you use auto number correctly your table(s) should get the correct values they need. The only thing you could do is search the numbering sequence for the LAST number and assume the next number yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it in another way : First I save my "header", then I update the lines with the value autogenerated for my header and then I save it again.

```
    public static void createLettering(List<ARRegister> lines)
    {
        // We build a new LELettering piece
        Lettrage graph = CreateInstance<Lettrage>();
        LELettering piece = new LELettering();
        piece.Status = ListStatus._OPEN;
        piece.LetteringDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        piece = graph.ARLetteringPiece.Insert(piece);
        // We fill the checked lines with the autonumber of the piece
        bool lineUpdated = false;
        foreach (ARRegister line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Selected.Value)
            {
                if (!lineUpdated)
                {
                    piece.BranchID = line.BranchID;
                    piece.AccountID = line.CustomerID;
                    piece = graph.ARLetteringPiece.Update(piece);
                    graph.Actions.PressSave();
                }
                line.GetExtension<ARRegisterLeExt>().LettrageCD = graph.ARLetteringPiece.Current.LetteringCD;
                graph.ARlines.Update(line);
                lineUpdated = true;
            }
        }
        // If there are lines in our piece, we save it
        // It saves our lettering piece and our modifications on the ARLines
        if (lineUpdated)
        {
            graph.Actions.PressSave();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship between your DACs (tables).

You can solve this by using the [PXDBChildIdentity](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=52e14c1d-8f10-4eb7-99c7-7ad12c4d9da5) in the fields of all the tables that need to store the new key.

For example, if your DAC's autonumber field is of type integer and is called `MyDAC.MyAutonumberField`.

You can add the attribute to all fields in your other DACs that need to store the value like this:

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(MyDAC.myAutonumberField))]
public virtual int? MyDACID { get; set; }
```

If the other DACs are "children" of your custom DAC you should use the [PXParent](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a916cba2-1f12-0c2b-8f70-31b1ecc05b99) attribute in all the child DACs on the field that references their parent like this:

```
[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
[PXDBDefault(typeof(MyDAC.myAutonumberField))]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<MyDAC,
                   Where<MyDAC.myAutonumberField,
                     Equal<Current<myAutonumberField>>>>))]
public virtual int? MyParentDacID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm getting an error while doing the PXDBChildIdentity thing. I'll investigate later.

Comment: @Maxime What error are you getting? Your solution may work, but it forces a second call to persist and Acumatica recommends using its built-in attributes when available.

Comment: here's the error : 10/31/2017 11:45:47 AM Error: 
Input string was not in a correct format. 

   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) 
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) 
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) 
   at PX.Data.PXDBChildIdentityAttribute.SourceRowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e).
Note that my other dac is not a children of my custom DAC.

Comment: @Maxime you are right, there is an error and this answer is incorrect. The correct way to use the `PXDBChildIdentity` and `PXParent` attributes is with identity fields. I incorrectly suggested you use it for an autonumbered field that normally is a string value generated by the framework. I will post a new answer with an alternative using `Row_Persisted` for future reference.